# How to change pointer value from assembly (x86)

Tags: c, assembly, x86

This is my C code that is used to change pointer value

```
     #include<stdio.h>
     #include<stdlib.h>
     typedef struct tcb tcb_t;

     struct tcb { 
     void* sp; 
     int id;        
     };


    void* changePointer(struct tcb*);
    int main(){
         struct tcb* s;
         s=malloc(sizeof(struct tcb*));
        printf("%p\n",changePointer(s));
        printf("%p\n",s);
   return 0;
  }
```

This is my assembly function (x86)

```
    .text
    .globl changePointer

   changePointer:
   push %ebp
   movl %esp, %ebp      
   movl 0x8(%ebp),%eax//original pointer value
   movl %ebp,%esp
   movl %ebp,0x8(%ebp) //it is to be the value  after changing
   popl %ebp
   ret
```

But  it didn't change pointer value inside the assembly function .Please explain where went wrong?

Comment: 1) Why did you put a C++ tag on this question, when the code is 'C'?  2) Why don't you write a very simple function (in 'C' I guess), that changes the pointer, generate the assembly listing from that function, and then use that as a guide in writing the assembly language equivalent?  3) Why would you want to change the pointer anyway?  It points to dynamically allocated memory, so how are you going to deallocate the memory using free() if the pointer has changed?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `s=malloc(sizeof(struct tcb));` ?

Comment: Here my intention is to change stack pointer one stack to another stack I have been creating user thread library.

Comment: Write a small C function doing (something like) what you want, and use that as a starting point. In any case, you can get what you want by a snippet of assembler, not a full function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function "changePointer" does not set its return value (in register eax).

<s>And it is not called "assembly", it is called "assembler"!</s>

Comment: Yes that is  true. But I what  is change the pointer value inside the assembly code

Comment: Here 0x8(%ebp) is the one that store pointer value what I tried to do is  change that value in assembly function.But it seems to be not change.

Answer (score 0):

```
movl %ebp,%esp
```

Whatever you want to do with this line: It does not work this way! EBP and ESP have the same value at this moment so the line simply does nothing (otherwise it would change the stack pointer what would cause the program to crash)!

```
movl %ebp,0x8(%ebp)
```

0x8(%ebp) is wrong here: After the instruction two lines above EAX contains the pointer to the pointer (not the pointer itself). So you must use 0x0(%eax) instead.

However you want eax to contain the old value of the pointer. Right?

So your code should look like this:

```
push %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
movl 0x8(%ebp),%ecx // <-- ecx holds a pointer to the pointer!
movl (%ecx),%eax    // <-- eax holds the old value
movl %ebp,(%ecx)    // <-- change the pointer
popl %ebp
ret
```

I still do not understand why you write the value of EBP to the pointer because EBP does not contain any useful value!

Comment: I just write value of EBP to the pointer because I wanted to check weather pointer(tcb* s) would be varied or not.Actually I want to go current stack to new stack (context switching in c) http://linux.die.net/man/3/getlogin

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which only uses a single assembler instruction and leaves the boilerplate to the compiler:

```
void changePointer(struct tcb *s)
{
    asm("movl %%esp, %0"
            : /* No output */
            : "m" (s->sp);
            : /* Nothing clobbered */
       );
}
```