# GCC linux 64 bit how to change stackpointer esp using inline assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

I am writing a code where I want to temporarily change the stack pointer to new location with some virtual address. I want to change esp register to address 0x4401000.

I have tried the solutions at
[How to change pointer value from assembly (x86)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278494/how-to-change-pointer-value-from-assembly-x86)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? How did that work? How *didn't* that work? Please elaborate. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I tried solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278494/how-to-change-pointer-value-from-assembly-x86

Comment: The stack pointer is rsp on x86_64 linux.

Comment: Coupld you plase write sample code for it? That will help